# Task scheduler with return code 2147942401 due to wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks, wkhtmltopdf

I am using task scheduler to run a batch script that runs a python script.

What my python script does is:

1. Query from Database
2. Export raw output to an excel file
3. Data Manipulation
4. Convert to PDF using wkhtmltopdf

When I run the script on command prompt, it works fine. But with task scheduler, I'm getting following error - action "C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" with return code 2147942401.

My observation is, when the task is completed with the error code, I've noticed that my excel file with raw output is updated, which means that the database query was working fine. I commented out the conversion to pdf and rerun it with task scheduler, and it was successful with no error.

Any idea how to solve this issue with wkhtmltopdf and task scheduler? Task is set up to run with highest privilege as well.